# How to use Multi language in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multilingual, cultureinfo, resourcemanager

I'm trying to prepare an application with more languages available.
I prepared the simplest example to learn it, I done a lot of tentative but I'm not able to do it.

```
CultureInfo cul = new CultureInfo("de-De");           
Resources.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-De");

label1.Text = TestLanguages.Properties.Resources.Saluto;
```

In my application I have two resources different resources , one for Italian language, one for German.

- Italian Resource : Saluto -> Ciao
- German Resource : Saluto -> Hallo

[image: Resources]

But I can't use the German one. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the UI culture of the currently executing thread.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-De");
label1.Text = TestLanguages.Properties.Resources.Saluto;
```

See the documentation for [Thread.CurrentUICulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the current culture used by the Resource Manager to look up culture-specific resources at run time.